# Error : Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. when trying to invoke the function app

Tags: azure

I am testing my deployed Azure function and getting the following error. My function runs locally connecting to Azure database but fails when its deployed and run. I have configured the application settings to read the secret url to the connection string.

[image]

This is how my connectionstring looks like

```
Server=tcp:ranjitazuredb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Srl;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usr;Password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Application setting - Url to the secret

```
https://srlcustomermanagervault.vault.azure.net/secrets/ConnectionString
```

Function

```
public  class GetCustomersOrders
    {
        private readonly ICustomerOrdersRepository _repo;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;


        public GetCustomersOrders(ICustomerOrdersRepository repo, IMapper mapper, TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
        }

        [FunctionName("GetCustomersOrders")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "customer-orders")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            this._telemetryClient.TrackTrace("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var customersOrders = _repo.GetCustomerOrders();
            return new OkObjectResult(_mapper.Map<List<CustomerOrdersViewModel>>(customersOrders));
        }
    }
```

This is how I have assigned the policy

[image]

Function start up

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace SRL.CustomerOrder
{
    internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
      
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
           
                var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");

                builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
                builder.Services.AddScoped<ISrlContext, CustomerManagerContext>();
                builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

                builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomerManagerContext>(options =>
                   options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

                builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerDetailsRepository, CustomerDetailsRepository>();
                builder.Services.AddTransient<ICustomerOrdersRepository, CustomerOrdersRepository>();
                builder.Services.AddTransient<IOrderDetailsRepository, OrderDetailsRepository>();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: looks like your using a keyvault for the reference.  does the function have access to keyvault?  I would probably through some error handling and make sure the function is getting the right DB.  It is possible that maybe you have an try catch and the connection string you think it is is not what it really is.  Also have you looked into this you should be able to set the connection string this way as well.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: Hi Ron, I have tried to write a log using telemetry client but that doesnt seem writing anything when i view the console. I have updated the post

Comment: I believe it could be because the connection string is read during startup hence exception is thrown even before. How would i add the telemetry to the startup

Comment: how are you storing the variable locally?  How are you storing it in Azure?  not sure if you looked at this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup  You might try to hard code the Connection string in the function just to see what happens.

Comment: I went through the link. One mistake that I noticed was instead of putting the actual connection string value in the appsetting, I had put the URL of the keyvault. I have now replaced that with the actual connection string. I am bit confused now. Where do I need to set the keyvault url

Comment: Another article says the best practice is storing the connection string as secret in the keyvault as I initially did and then adding the keyvault url to the app settings

Comment: It is, but did using the actual connection string work for you?  The first link I shared with you is how you should reference the setting  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references  your example would be Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://srlcustomermanagervault.vault.azure.net/secrets/ConnectionString
)  The documentation says you need the version id but you do not, (it is a bug that it works).  Azure is working on a release so that it works without a version which should probably be out in preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming the connection string worked when you used it directly in the app settings I would check out this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

So in your example you would use

@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://srlcustomermanagervault.vault.azure.net/secrets/ConnectionString
)

The documentation says you need the version id but you do not, (it is a bug that it works).  Azure is working on a release so that it works without a version which should probably be out in preview by now and if not shortly.  I have talked with several people and have it working for a client without the version.

Comment: My application settings currently have a key ConnectionSetting, So is the above to be set as value for it. I am getting the following error when doing that 020-07-14T23:02:37Z   [Error]   An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'SRL.CustomerOrder.Models.CustomerManagerContext'.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'microsoft.keyvault(secreturi'.

Comment: Sorry c&p kills (copy and paste).  I forgot the @.  It should be @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://srlcustomermanagervault.vault.azure.net/secrets/ConnectionString ) and not Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://srlcustomermanagervault.vault.azure.net/secrets/ConnectionString )

Comment: I did notice that and added it but now getting error   An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'SRL.CustomerOrder.Models.CustomerManagerContext'.
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: '@microsoft.keyvault(secreturi'.

Comment: Highly frustrating

Comment: One more thing I have noticed . Just sharing

Comment: Check out https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23250  They had a similar issue and it was their KeyVault Settings

Comment: I have passed that error. Thanks Ron and now the error i get is Cannot open server 'ranjitazuredb' requested by the login. Client with IP address '51.140.188.39' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#create-and-manage-ip-firewall-rules  that should get you there.  I would just goto the set server firewall and then if allow azure services is off just turn that on and you will probably be good.  if not you can add the IP listed above.

Comment: Bravo!!!. It worked. Thanks Ron a lot guiding me through the steps and sharing some useful links. You have made my day